# why do we use entrySet() method and use the returned set to iterate a map?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, iterator

Usually we write this to get the keys and values from a map.

```
Map m=new HashMap();
Set s=map.entrySet();
Iterator i=s.iterator()
while(s.hasNext()){
    Map.Entry m= (map.Entry) s.next();
    System.out.println(""+m.getKey()+""+ m.getValue());
}
```

Why do we iterate using a set why not directly map?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is as close to iterating over the map as we can because you have to say whether you want just the keys, just the values or the whole key/value entry.  For Sets and Lists, there is only one option so, no need to have a separate method to do this.

BTW: This is how I would iterate over a Map.  Note the use of generics, the for-each loop and the LinkedHashMap so the entries appear in some kind of logical order. TreeMap would be another good choice.

```
Map<K,V> m=new LinkedHashMap<K,V>();
for(Map.Entry<K,V> entry: m.entrySet())
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
```

In Java 8 you can write

```
m.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v));
```

Comment: So no need for the iterator?

Comment: @Jwan622 The for-each loop was added in Java 5.0 (2004) which would manage the Iterator for you. For collections there is still an Iterator but you don't need to use it directly (unless you want to remove entries)

Comment: Ah so there's an iterator behind the scenes... got it. So generally speaking we take the map object, call entrySet on it to turn it into a set object, and then we take iterate over the set object by slicing it into Map.Entry's? How would you say it?

Answer (score 6):

Because, logically, a map is a Set *collection* of key-value pairs - which is what a Map.Entry represents.  Iteration is an operation on a collection generally, not a map specifically.

However, I've often wondered myself why `Map` doesn't implement `Iterable<Map.Entry<K,V>>` et al and provide an `iterator()` method over the map entries directly instead of requiring an entry set (which it could certainly do also to provide a full `Set` API.

Answer (score 3):

Map is a collection of pairs of things, right (Entries). So you can iterate over entries, or iterate over the keys only (map.keySet()), or over the value only (map.values()). What else do you want to be able to iterate over?

Answer (score 2):

Because Java doesn't have a better syntax to do it. (Yours can be improved)

It would be nice to

```
for(String key, Integer val : map)
    print(key, val);
```

or

```
map.foreach (String key, Integer val) -> print(key, val);
```

but Java doesn't have these.

Comment: the problem is deeper than syntax.  You can't do this using old-style `for` loops, or `while` loops either.